# JAVA read a char enter - '\r' in loop from keyboard

Tags: java

How Can I read a char enter - '\r' in loop from keyboard ?
I test a 2 methods.
First method is a: 
In first turn loop for can't stop in line znak = (char)System.in.read(); I don't know why that is.

```
public static void lista() {
    Ewidencja tmp = null;
    char znak = 0;
    for(Ewidencja el: Lista)
    {
        if (znak == 'Q')
        {
            el = tmp;
        }

        tmp = el;

        System.out.println("[Enter] - zapisz");
        System.out.println("[Q] - cofnij");

        try {
            znak = (char)System.in.read();
            System.out.println(znak);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(znak == '\r')
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if(znak != 'Q')
        {
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Second method is use a class Scanner, but this method don't read char Enter '\r'.

Comment: you can check for the empty string. `if(znak == '') //thats a newline`

Comment: sometimes it's `\r`, some other times it's `\r\n` ... but really, you should be using scanner.

Comment: scanner don't read char Enter. In debug when I press enter, I debuger show me '\r'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using some of your code from your question, this is how to get a scanner to detect the enter key being pressed.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

for(Ewidencja el: Lista) {
    znak = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println(znak);

    if(znak.equals("")) {
        continue;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a `BufferedInputReader` instead of directly accessing the System.In:

BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)) ;

Now you can decide whether you like to read a `char` or something else (`String, Integer...`)

```
String string ="";
try{
   string = bufferedReader.readLine() ;
}catch(IOException e){
   System.exit(-1);
}
if(string.trim().equals("")){
   continue;
}else  if(string.trim().equalsIgnoreCase("Q")){
   System.exit(-1);
}
...
```

That way you avoid detecting `'\n'` or `'\r'` and handling "unclear" input from users is easier ('q' != 'Q' and a char can't be read if the user accidentally types two letters etc..)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for any response. This fragment of code very help me, because I don't know method equals.

```
if(znak.equals("")) 
{ 
    continue; 
}
```